# Which Hindrances are counteracted or enhance by the 37 and Jhana Factors?

Tags: reference-request, meditation-hindrances, jhana, five-hindrances, bodhipakkhiyadhamma

If you take Jhana factors or the 37 Factors, many of them counteract one of the Hindrances. So if these factors (and perhaps other factors mentioned in the Tripitaka) are grouped with the hindrance they counteract or enhance, what would this grouping look like? I.e.,

- each hindrance
- with the factors that counteract it
- and the factor that enhance them either as a single factor or pair of factor being unbalanced

An answer should minimally include the Jhana and 37 Factors, and references to the Tripitaka.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an outline of a few things I have collected so far:

> **Sensual Desire**

...

> **One-pointedness** of mind, of the *factors of absorption* (jhananga);
>
> **Mindfulness**, of the *spiritual faculties* (indriya);
>
> **Mindfulness**, of the *factors of enlightenment* (bojjhanga).

---

> **Ill-Will**
>
> ...
>
> **Rapture**, of the *factors of absorption* (jhananga);
>
> **Faith**, of the *spiritual faculties* (indriya);
>
> **Rapture** and **equanimity**, of the *factors of enlightenment* (bojjhanga).

---

> **Sloth and Torpor**
>
> ...
>
> **Applied thought**, of the *factors of absorptions* (jhananga);
>   **Energy**, of the *spiritual faculties* (indriya);
>   **Investigation of reality**, **energy** and **rapture**, of the *factors of enlightenment* (bojjhanga).
>
> When the mind is sluggish, ***it is not the proper time for cultivating the following factors of enlightenment: tranquillity, concentration and equanimity***, because a sluggish mind can hardly be aroused by them.
>
> When the mind is sluggish, ***it is the proper time for cultivating the following factors of enlightenment: investigation of reality, energy and rapture***, because a sluggish mind can easily be aroused by them.
>
> — SN 46:53

---

> **Restlessness and Remorse**
>
> ...
>
> **Rapture**, of the *factors of absorption* (jhananga);
>
> **Concentration**, of the *spiritual faculties* (indriya);
>
> **Tranquillity**, **concentration** and **equanimity**, of the *factors of enlightenment* (bojjhanga).
>
> When the mind is restless ***it is not the proper time for cultivating the following factors of enlightenment: investigation of the doctrine, energy and rapture***, because an agitated mind can hardly be quietened by them.
>
> When the mind is restless, ***it is the proper time for cultivating the following factors of enlightenment: tranquillity, concentration and equanimity***, because an agitated mind can easily be quietened by them.
>
> — SN 46:53

---

> **Doubt**
>
> ...
>
> **Reflection**, of the *factors of absorption* (jhananga);
>
> **Wisdom**, of the *spiritual faculties* (indriya);
>
> **Investigation of reality**, of the *factors of enlightenment* (bojjhanga).

Source: [The Five Mental Hindrances and Their Conquest](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel026.html), [SN 46.53 - Fire](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn46.53)